# Is there a way to call a multiple and variable number of branches of a function recursively without getting nested values?

Tags: python, recursion

I've encountered the following issue while trying to create a list with all the possible permutations of a list of digits:

In order to make a call to a variable number of functions recursively, I've stored all the functions I want to call each time in a dictionary, and then I make the call to all the values stored in it.
The problem is that the results I get are nested inside a list for each call made to the values of the dictionary.

**Is there a way to call a multiple and variable number of branches of a function recursively without getting nested values?**

This is the code:

```
def permutations(lista, n=0, per = ''):

    f_dict = {}

    if n != len(lista):
        for i in range(len(lista)):
            if str(i) not in per:
                f_dict.update({i : permutations(lista, n+1 , per + str(i))})  
        call = [f_dict[i] for i in f_dict]
        return call
    return per

digits = [1,2,3]
print(permutations(digits))
```

It prints the following list:

> [[['012'], ['021']], [['102'], ['120']], [['201'], ['210']]]

But I want it in the form :

> ['012', '021', '102', '120', '201', '210']

This is my first time using stackoverflow, let me know if you need more info or I haven't been clear with the quiestion

Thanks beforehand for the help!!

P.D. I know I can create a list of permutations with the *itertools* module or flatten the list using another function, but that's not the objective of this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can fix your approach as follows:

```
def permutations(lista, n=0, per = ''):
    f_dict = {}
    if n != len(lista):
        for i in range(len(lista)):
            if str(i) not in per:
                f_dict[i] = permutations(lista, n+1 , per + str(i))
        return [x for v in f_dict.values() for x in v]  # unpack and chain the lists
    return [per]  # return a singleton list of strings

>>> print(permutations([1, 2, 3]))
['012', '021', '102', '120', '201', '210']
```

You have to make sure to always return the same type, in this case a list of strings. You were returning a single string in your base case and a list thereof in the recursive case.

Btw, the content of the list that you pass is never used. You might just pass the length itself:

```
>>> print(permutations([6,5,4]))
['012', '021', '102', '120', '201', '210']
```

A canonical recursive implementation via recursive generator would look like:

```
def permutations(lst):
    if lst:
        for i, x in enumerate(lst):
            for perm in permutations(lst[:i] + lst[i+1:]):
                yield [x] + perm
    else:
        yield []

>>> list(permutations([6,5,4]))
[[6, 5, 4], [6, 4, 5], [5, 6, 4], [5, 4, 6], [4, 6, 5], [4, 5, 6]]
```